# MongoDB aggregation: count real documents after unwind operation?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here is my schema:

```
company: String
model: String
tags: [String] // array of strings
```

Here is my query:

```
{ "$unwind": "$tags" },
{ "$group": {
    "_id": {
        "company": "$company",
        "model": "$model",
        "tag": "$tags"
    },
    "tagCount": { "$sum": 1 },
    "reviewCount": { "$sum" : 1}
}},
{ "$group": {
    "_id": { 
        "company": "$_id.company",
        "model": "$_id.model",
     },
     "tags": { "$push": { "tag": "$_id.tag", "count": "$tagCount" },
     "count": { "$sum": "$reviewCount" }
}}
```

Notice that I have `tagCount` and `reviewCount`.
`tagCount` must show the number of tag matches for some model across different reviews.
`reviewCount` must show the number of reviews for some model.

However the `reviewCount` is currently shows an incorrect number, because of the `unwind` operation.

**What is an efficient way to get the number of documents of some `model` after you unwind `tags` list in each document?**

Note: I also tried to do this:

```
{ "$group": {
  "_id": {
    "company": "$company",
    "model": "$model"
  },
  "reviewCount": { "$sum": 1}
}},
{ "$unwind": "$tags" },
{ "$group": {
    "_id": {
        "company": "$_id.company",
        "model": "$_id.model",
        "tag": "$tags"
    },
    "tagCount": { "$sum": 1 }
}},
{ "$group": {
    "_id": { 
        "company": "$_id.company",
        "model": "$_id.model",
     },
     "tags": { "$push": { "tag": "$_id.tag", "count": "$tagCount" },
     "count": { "$sum": "$reviewCount" }
}}
```

But I got an empty array as a response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are looking at is that you want to count the distinct occurances of some data in an array ( so "tags" ) within some other grouping criteria, and then only count the ditinct occurances of the other criteria itself once the "tags" is removed and placed in the result as an array.

The solution is quite logical, so if you step back and look at the data, consider this facsimilie:

```js
{ "a" : "a", "b" : "b", "c" : [ "c", "d" ] }
{ "a" : "a", "b" : "b", "c" : [ "c", "d" ] }
{ "a" : "a", "b" : "b", "c" : [ "d", "e" ] }
{ "a" : "a", "b" : "b", "c" : [ "d", "e" ] }
{ "a" : "a", "b" : "b", "c" : [ "e", "f" ] }
```

There are "five" documents in total with the same "a" and "b" values, and there are of course going to be different values for "c". To get distinct "c" counts you are going to need to [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and then [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) on "a", "b" and "c":

```js
{ "$unwind": "$c"},
{ "$group": {
  "_id": {
    "a": "$a",
    "b": "$b",
    "c": "$c"
  },
  "count": { "$sum": 1 }
}},
```

Looking at the result:

```js
{ "_id" : { "a" : "a", "b" : "b", "c" : "e" }, "count" : 3 }
{ "_id" : { "a" : "a", "b" : "b", "c" : "f" }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "a" : "a", "b" : "b", "c" : "d" }, "count" : 4 }
{ "_id" : { "a" : "a", "b" : "b", "c" : "c" }, "count" : 2 }
```

The "unique" combinations there has dropped down to "four" documents based on the distinct values that are available. Now you could look at that and say *"Well the total counts add up to 'ten', an the arrays always have 'two' elements, so that means 'five' right?"*, but this is **never** a real world scenario, and the array lengths are going to differ.

How do you get the counts of documents then? Well from here, you cannot. The only thing you could do within a single aggregation pipeline is `$group` first on "a" and "b", using `$push` to keep all the array content in "c".
That allows you to count the "a" and "b" combinations correctly as "five".

Then you would `$unwind` "twice" since this is an array of arrays, and continue on from where this started to count those distinct keys, keeping the `$first` occurance of the initial count on the "pair".

```js
   { "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "a": "$a",
        "b": "$b"
      },
      "c": { "$push": "$c" },
      "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$c" },
    { "$unwind": "$c" },
    { "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "a": "$_id.a",
        "b": "$_id.b",
        "c": "$c"
      },
      "docCount": { "$first": "$count" },
      "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "a": "$_id.a",
        "b": "$_id.b"
      },
      "tags": { "$push": { "tag": "$c", "count": "$count" } },
      "count": { "$first": "$docCount" }
    }}
```

But that is not "efficient", as you are grouping together then "pulling apart" just to add up something else.

The "efficient" way to handle this is to run "two" aggregation operations, and do them in "parallel". Then you can combine the results of the operations in a simple hash merge, or using something like [nedb](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb) which does that but in a MongoDB collection handling like way:

```js
var async = require('async'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    DataStore = require('nedb'),
    db = new DataStore();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var data = [
  { "a" : "a", "b" : "b", "c" : [ "c", "d" ] },
  { "a" : "a", "b" : "b", "c" : [ "c", "d" ] },
  { "a" : "a", "b" : "b", "c" : [ "d", "e" ] },
  { "a" : "a", "b" : "b", "c" : [ "d", "e" ] },
  { "a" : "a", "b" : "b", "c" : [ "e", "f" ] }
];

var dataSchema = new Schema({
  a: String,
  b: String,
  c: [String]
});

var Data = mongoose.model( 'Data', dataSchema, 'data' );

async.series(
  [
    function(callback) {
      async.each([Data],function(model,callback) {
        model.remove({},callback);
      },callback);
    },

    function(callback) {
      async.each(data,function(doc,callback) {
        Data.create(doc,callback);
      },callback);
    },

    function(callback) {
      async.parallel(
        [
          function(callback) {
            Data.aggregate(
              [
                { "$group": {
                  "_id": {
                    "a": "$a",
                    "b": "$b"
                  },
                  "count": { "$sum": 1 }
                }}
              ],
              function(err,results) {
                if (err) callback(err);
                async.each(results,function(result,callback) {
                  db.update(
                    { "key": result._id },
                    { "$set": { "count": result.count } },
                    { "upsert": true },
                    callback
                  );
                },callback);
              }
            );
          },

          function(callback) {
            Data.aggregate(
              [
                { "$unwind": "$c" },
                { "$group": {
                  "_id": {
                    "a": "$a",
                    "b": "$b",
                    "c": "$c"
                  },
                  "count": { "$sum": 1 }
                }},
                { "$group": {
                  "_id": {
                    "a": "$_id.a",
                    "b": "$_id.b"
                  },
                  "tags": { "$push": { "tag": "$_id.c", "count": "$count" } }
                }}
              ],
              function(err,results) {
                if (err) callback(err);
                async.each(results,function(result,callback) {
                  db.update(
                    { "key": result._id },
                    { "$set": { "tags": result.tags } },
                    { "upsert": true },
                    callback
                  );
                },callback)
              }
            );
          }
        ],
        function(err) {
          if (err) callback(err);
          db.find({},function(err,results) {
            if (err) callback(err);
            console.log(JSON.stringify( results, undefined, 2 ));
            callback()
          });
        }
      );
    }
  ],
  function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    mongoose.disconnect()
  }
);
```

Which shows the results from queries that are actually run at the same time, but produce a combined result:

```js
[
  {
    "key": {
      "a": "a",
      "b": "b"
    },
    "count": 5,
    "_id": "cL5oaVlIrKluKSo0",
    "tags": [
      {
        "tag": "e",
        "count": 3
      },
      {
        "tag": "f",
        "count": 1
      },
      {
        "tag": "d",
        "count": 4
      },
      {
        "tag": "c",
        "count": 2
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This is "much" for efficient than trying to juggle within a single pipeline and produces the same results, and much faster as the total "parallel" runtime will be a lot less.

This also scales well as an approach, as where if the results were too large for memory, then you can basically "swap out" the writes to the `nedb` based datastore for an actual collection on the MongoDB server. The "upsert" actions here work well to "combine" the data for the overall result, so this is how it is used.

The key thing to consider is to not make the aggregation pipeline process do more work than it really should be doing. If obtaining the results from different queries makes sense, then use it. It is more than often the most efficient way to handle the problem.